# flush privilleges of spring security

Tags: java, spring, security, reboot, privilege

I use the spring security as my security framework, but when I change some privillege of users I must reboot my app server(Tomcat) to let it work, Is there any other way to flush the privilege without reboot app server ? Maybe spring security offered some API which I don't know?

thanks for any help!

Comment: in my experience it's always a good idea to look in springs code how it works and find extension points where my own logic fits in

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to store login,password and roles information in database and the use `JdbcDetailsService`  and configure sql statements for authentication and auhtorization in xml

Comment: I have already stored the privileges info in database. And I want to know how to flush it when I changed something in it.